# DSolve: Interpretation of the result

Tags: differential-equations

```
DSolve[1+1*y'[x]+(y[x]/(y[x]-1))+1*y[x]*y[x]-1*y[x]*y[x]*y[x]==0,y[x],x]

Solve[1/2 RootSum[1-2#1+#1^2-2#1^3+#1^4&, (-Log[-#1+y[x]]+Log[-#1+y[x]]#1)/(-1+#1-3#1^2+2#1^3)&]==x+C[1],y[x]]
```

[image]

I could not understand the results of the run. In addition, I want to draw the graph according to the results, but I could not make it. Any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: What are the results of your code, and which part is unclear specifically? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This is a separable ODE. Maple produces `x` as a fnction of `y` in a closed form.